# How to match object in array strictly with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I need to check that an Array contains an Object that matches a given structure.

I already tried this:

```js
const myArray = [{ name: 'Mete', age: 19, phone: '123456' }];

expect(myArray).toEqual(          
  expect.arrayContaining([      
    expect.objectContaining({   
      name: 'Mete',
      age: 19
    })
  ])
)

// Throws no error
```

It should not match because the object in the array has an additional property "phone".

I need something like **toStrictEqual()** combined with arrayContaining().

Comment: `expect(myArray[0]).toEqual({ name: 'Mete', age: 19 })`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i don't have the index of my Object. It could be anywhere in the array.

Comment: What about trying to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the element or [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array?

Answer (score 0):

With `every` array function, you can get the result:

```js
const strictlyEquals = (arr, props) => arr.every(o=>Object.keys(o).every(i=>props.includes(i)));

console.log(strictlyEquals([{name:'Test', age: 20}], ['name', 'age']));
console.log(strictlyEquals([{name:'Test', age: 20, phone:'Test'}], ['name', 'age']));
```

If you have to match complete object then:

```js
const strictlyEquals = (arr, props) => arr.every(o=> Object.keys(o).length===Object.keys(props).length && Object.keys(o).every(i=>o[i]===props[i]));

console.log(strictlyEquals([{name:'Test', age: 20},{name:'Test', age: 20}], {name:'Test', age: 20}));
```

Comment: `expect(strictlyEquals(myArray)).toBe(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`.toEqual(value)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#toequalvalue) to test each object in the array, which will stop iteration and return `true` on the first assertion that passes the expectation. Otherwise, `false` will be returned and the final `expect` statement will fail.

The technique here is to `catch` the exceptions thrown from the assertions and convert them to `false` results:

```js
const expected = {name: 'Mete', age: 19};

const myArray = [{ name: 'Mete', age: 19, phone: '123456' }];

const found = myArray.some(obj => {
  try {
    expect(obj).toEqual(expected);
    return true;
  }
  catch {
    return false;
  }
});

expect(found).toBeTruthy();
```